# How to configure Sharepoint 2013 enabling access through browser and php-soap

Tags: php, rest, soap, sharepoint-2013

We have a Sharepoint 2013 server configured to be accessed with browser (Chrome, IE, FF) or filesystem (Form based authentication in IIS)
I need to create folders and modify files from a php 5.5 server with SOAP (with PHP-Sharepoint-lists-API libreay) but authentication fails with a 401 error code.

Changing IIS authentication to Anonymous + Basic + Windows allows to acces SP from php with SOAP, but disables IE and Chrome access.

Is it posible to configure IIS autentication to enable access from both ways?

I have tried to use REST calls from the php server, but fails to authenticate.

¿Any ideas?